# I got this error for multiremote capabilities whre I want to use object model: Error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I need help on how to use object model when I have multiremote capabilities as below:
Fyi, this is webdriverio, and use multiremote appium and chromedriver

```
   capabilities: {

        myBrowser: {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 9515,
            "path": "/",
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                //browserVersion: '122.0.6261.39'
            }
        },
        myMobile: {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 4723,
            capabilities: {
                platformName: 'Android',
                'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel 4',
                'appium:platformVersion': '11.0',
                'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2', //make sure it's in UIAutomator2, not UiAutomator2
                'appium:app': path.join(process.cwd(), 'app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk')
            }
        }
    },
```

Let say, my screen object are as below:

```
class TestScreen{
    get firstText(){
        return $('//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc="Accessibility"]');
    }

    async clickText(){
        await this.firstText.click();
    }
}

module.exports = new TestScreen();
```

So I tried it in my spec file, but it failed:

```
const { firstText } = require("../screen/test-screen.spec");


describe('test run', () =>{
    it('test run', async () => {
        await myMobile.firstText.click();
        
    })
})
```

I want the code to be able to use object model with the multiremote capabilities

Answer (score 0):

You're using multi-remote capabilities, you'll need to access the browser instances

```
const { myBrowser, myMobile } = browser;

class TestScreen {
    get firstText() {
        return $('//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc="Accessibility"]');
    }

    async clickText() {
        await this.firstText.click();
    }
}

module.exports = new TestScreen();
```

In your test spec file, you can then use the multi-remote instances like this:

```
const testScreen = require("../screen/test-screen.spec");

describe('test run', () => {
    it('test run', async () => {
        await myMobile.url('your-app-url'); // Navigate to your app URL if required
        await testScreen.clickText(); // Perform actions on your mobile instance
    })
})
```

Make sure to replace `'your-app-url'` with the URL of your mobile application if needed.

Comment: I'm totally a newbie in this.

1. What should I do once I access the browser instances? How do I use it?
2. What does it mean by 'your-app-url'? I use an app build and access it by using the path.

Thanks in advance for your help!